# peewee update thrown exception 'UnknownField' object has no attribute 'get_sort_key'

Tags: peewee

code:

```
query = Order.update(is_review=1, review_time=review_time).where(Order.order_sn == order_sn)
query.execute()
```

exception:

```
cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2952, in execute
    sql, params = ctx.sql(query).query()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 601, in sql
    return obj.__sql__(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2363, in __sql__
    for k, v in sorted(self._update.items(), key=ctx.column_sort_key):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 555, in column_sort_key
    return item[0].get_sort_key(self)
AttributeError: 'UnknownField' object has no attribute 'get_sort_key'
```

environment：
peewee version:3.9.5
python:3.7

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have posted this as a GitHub issue on the Peewee issue tracker as well. I've responded to your ticket and will paste my response here for anyone else:

> You are clearly using models generated using the pwiz tool. If pwiz cannot determine the right field type to use for a column, it uses a placeholder "UnknownField". You will need to edit your model definitions and replace the UnknownField with an appropriate field type (e.g. TextField, IntegerField, whatever) if you wish to be able to use it in queries.